# c# Write more item from the list not one

Tags: c#, list

```
public static void work_3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3_work");
        int chosenday = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Cardatas cdat = Cardata.Find(x => x.Day.Equals(chosenday));
        Console.WriteLine($"The traffic at {chosenday}: {cdat.time.ToShortTimeString()} {cdat.licenseplate}");
    }
```

I have a data list about car datas
`2 19:32 CEG305 574 8912 1`
`2 19:35 CEG304 578 8932 1`
like this, and I managed to write out the information what I wanted to but It just write one data of the many.

```
private static List<Cardatas> Cardata= new List<Cardatas>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Linq extension `Where` instead of `Find` to get all the matching elements, then loop on the result enumerable:

```
    IEnumerable<Cardatas> allCdats = Cardata.Where(x => x.Day.Equals(chosenday));
    foreach (Cardatas cdat in allCdats)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The traffic at {chosenday}: cdat.time.ToShortTimeString()} {cdat.licenseplate}");
    }
```

Note: you'll need `using System.Linq` and `using System.Collections.Generics` for the above code.